# System.Data.SqlClient with .NET 4.0

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sqlclient

How to install System.Data.SqlClient to a .NET 4.0 project?  When trying to install nuget package is VS, getting error package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework.  Can I go to a earlier version than 4.8.2?

Comment: Don't do this. Just don't.  Support ended for .NET 4.0 *5 1/2 years ago*. You are putting your project and users at serious risk by continuing to use outdated frameworks.

Comment: That's perhaps a little extreme, but agree with David - there isn't much point using older frameworks. If you're stuck with it, then I'm not sure why there is a problem - .net 4 framework included System.Data.SqlClient out of the box, just reference it. You don't have to install a nuget package

Comment: In .NET 4.0, I'm pretty sure all you need is an assembly reference to System.Data, which is usually added *by default* in most boilerplate projects. No nugets required. However, I fully support David's sentiment.

Comment: I'm voting to close for two reasons: 1)`System.Data.SqlClient` was part of the runtime in .NET 4.0 and even .NET 1.0, when there was no NuGet, so the question is unclear. Why not just add `using System.Data.SqlClient;`? There's no code that actually demonstrates a problem, not even an error message 2) .NET 4.0 is out of support for **several** years. And won't even be available in any machine unless you target Windows XP. In all others, installing a newer runtime like 4.5 would replace 4.0. 4.x runtimes are binary replacements.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: Voting to close because the question is unclear is one thing, but the subject matter being out of support is not a reason to close -- there are many tags on SO for unsupported and outdated technologies that continue to receive questions, and Meta calls this out as valid ([for example](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/327855/4137916), though others are not hard to find). "Target a later version" might be part of an answer, though, as is commenting to confirm whether the OP *really* needs to target .NET 4 (which is unlikely, but not completely impossible).

Comment: @JeroenMostert I should have phrased this differently. The question isn't just unclear, it's easy to disprove it and has no code that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @JeroenMostert btw there are dozens of similar questions lately that show no attempt to even read the docs except .... the clear docs we used to learn ADO.NET no longer exist or cause confusion to new developers. `learn.microsoft.com` is full of EF Core docs and tutorials but all that's left of ADO.NET makes sense only to people that used it from the start. Especially when it comes to obsolete parts like table adapters.

Comment: Well, the fact that Microsoft's usual policy for documentation on things they've declared obsolete is "burn it yesterday, scour it from the archives and pretend it never existed" makes it extra important to keep avenues like SO open for questions on them (even if this one doesn't really qualify as such). It just means "RTFM" becomes harder to use as the stock response. ...also, I shall not weep for table adapters, but that's neither here nor there. :P

Answer (score -1):

As mentioned in the comments above, the .net 4 framework includes System.Data.SqlClient, you only need to add a reference to your project.

From this [document](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Data.SqlClient/), you can know that the minimum version of the .net framework that Microsoft.Data.SqlClient depends on is .NETFramework 4.6.1.

For changing the version when downloading the package, you can select other versions in the Version drop-down box.
[image]

Comment: There's no reason to add that package. `System.Data.SqlClient` is bundled with the .NET Framework itself.

Comment: The above comments have explained in detail that the .net 4 framework includes System.Data.SqlClient, I just explained his error and the use of System.Data.SqlClient